# No power at light fixture

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, circuit-breaker

[image]I am installing a new vanity light fixture, but after installation it did not turn on. I reinstalled the old one and now that one doesn't turn on either at that fixture. So I used a multi-meter on the wires and it does not detect any AC voltage - I've checked the breaker and it has not tripped. I am out of ideas of where else or what else to check.
Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Did the old one work before you started?

Comment: Did you have any arc or spark incidents during installation that maybe you aren't mentioning?

Comment: Did you try turning the breaker off and on again? Some breakers do not move much when they trip

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved?

Comment: Thank you all - yes the old one was working previously, and no issues like sparking that I noticed. I am just updating the light fixture there was nothing wrong with the old one. I have tried the breaker several times now, still no good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turned out, it was the dimmer which must have  been shorted by the new light fixture. While the light fixture is dimmer compatible, I guess the old dimmer wasn't up to the task - and was probably why there was no power getting to the light fixture. bought and installed a new dimmer and now it works!

Comment: Thanks for coming back and answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a GFCI outlet in the bathroom or surrounding area you need to reset it.

Comment: I have reset it - and still no good

Answer (score 1):

Check this bathroom and all the others for a tripped GFI. There could be a GFI somewhere in the house- often in another bathroom- that controls this fixture. BTW, you should have killed power to this fixture at the circuit breaker before you started.

Comment: Good question that should be posted as a comment to the question, since it's not an answer

Comment: Thanks @Ack. I moved the question and made the rest of it a statement.

Comment: I have checked for the GFI which is in another bathroom, it never tripped and I have reset it in hopes it might help but still no good. And yes I did kill the power before working on it. Thank you though, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If this fixture controlled by a wall switch, check for power on the always hot side of the switch and on the switched side with switch on.

If the power is present on the hot side of the switch, but not on the switched side, and the switch is connected through backwire holes, change the wires to the side screws. If switch still doesn't send power through, get another switch. Don't connect through old type spring loaded backwire holes. New type screw secured backwire clamps are fine and are perhaps even more secure than looping around the screw.